# Console error present even when fail is caught?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-deferred

I'm doing some ajax first time... code:

**jQuery**

```
form_ajax_promise = $.ajax({
  type : "POST",
  url :  '/orders/create_or_update',
  dataType: 'json', 
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data : JSON.stringify(params)
})
form_ajax_promise.then(
  function(response) {
    formSuccess(response)
  },
  function(response) {
    formFailure(response) 
  }
)
```

**Controller**

```
def create_or_update
  if @object.save
    # corresponds with formSuccess
    render json: {"id" => @order.id}, status: 200
  else
    # corresponds with formFailure
    render json: {"errors"=> @order.errors.full_messages}, status: 400
  end
end
```

The `success` path works well. In testing the `failure` route, assuming that `formFailure` is just a simple function...

```
function formFailure(response){
  console.log("successfully inside of formFailure")
}
```

What I'm noticing is happening is that the `console` shows the appropriate log message as above, but also shows me an error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
```

Is this error supposed to happen? I felt like since I provided an adequate `fail` in the `$.then` it shouldn't?

**EDIT**

Apologies for the confusion, this is NOT a case of multiple render/re-direct, I was just being lazy and cutting out the other code, since I was only trying to describe fail behavior. My mistake. Code is edited above.

Comment: You are doing a render with `status: 400`, So this is the right behaviour.

Comment: Two question (1) Which version of jQuery? (2) Is `form_ajax_promise` handled further?

Comment: 1) jQuery 2.2.4, 2) it is not handled further

Comment: @Sajan Ok definitely didn't know that! I guess my impression is that console errors pop up when there are things not caught/handled by the code, and I thought my code was sufficiently handling the error case. Given what you're telling me, that's false, so I think I'll just respond even in error cases with status: 200 and just append something to the data field that says that's not the case. Is that more appropriate do you think?

Comment: With jQuery <3, a promise error handler doesn't catch as per Promises/A+ spec. An error propagates down an promise chain unless an error handler specifically returns a fulfilled promise (or one that will become fulfilled), in which case the chain will follow its success path. You say that `form_ajax_promise` is not handled further, but that's the only thing that would make sense; error not caught by error handler, then some later error handler logs the error.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this will do. This will return you `success` when `@order` is saved successfully and `error` when `@order` is invalid

```
def create_or_update
  # Your code here to create or update @order
  if @order.save
    # corresponds with formSuccess
    render json: {"id" => @order.id}, status: 200
  else
    # corresponds with formFailure
    render json: {"errors"=> @order.errors.full_messages}, status: 400
  end
end
```

Comment: sorry i was just abbreviating the code and being lazy, that IS what's happening

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this kind of code results in Multiple Render or Redirect Error. You don't  use multiple render or redirects in same function without using a conditional/branching statement like if or use return statements.

In your case,

`render json: {"errors"=> @order.errors.full_messages}, status: 400`

is been rendered which directs the browser that error code 400 is received (which is for bad request), so you are seeing this error in console.
Better use code which @Deepak Mahakale shared above.

Hope this helps